# Fetch Workflows through Partner WSDL (JAVA)

Tags: workflow

How to fetch Workflow Rules,WorkflowTask ,WorkflowAlert, WorkflowEmailRecipient ,WorkflowFieldUpdate, WorkflowOutboundMessage through partner wsdl in Java.

Im Querying the above object and its throwing an exception.

[InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE'
 exceptionMessage='
SELECT Id FROM workflows
               ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:16
sObject type 'workflows' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'
]
 row='1'
 column='16'
]
]

Answer (score 3):

The Partner API doesn't have any functionality for querying metadata (with some exceptions, such as Apex Classes and Reports). You'll want to use the [MetaData API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm) for downloading a list of workflows and their component field updates and alerts as well as any other metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It would be good if Salesforce exposes the workflow information in Partner WSDL.